# Magento Blocks displays in the footer?

Tags: xml, magento, block

This is probably a pretty basic question. I made a custom block in my page.xml and I placed it in the header block. But it shows at the bottom of my page. I searched for tutorials and user guides, but I couldn't find anything.

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
    <block type="page/template_links" name="serie.menu" as="serieMenu" output="toHtml" template="page/html/series.phtml" />
</block>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect your HTML, see where the block HTML is being rendered.  If it's outputting the HTML in the header, but appearing at the bottom, it's most likely CSS positioning the block where you see it.

I recommend not modifying page.xml, but creating a local.xml file in your layouts directory and including your block definition there.  You can use the `<reference>` tags to target a specific block, and inject your block inside of it.

For example, since you want to target the block named `header`, you can use `<reference name="header">` to target that specific block, and define your own block definition.

To do so, you would create the file **/layouts/local.xml** file in your theme directory, and include the following in the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <!-- Default handle, loaded on most pages -->
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="page/template_links" name="serie.menu" as="serieMenu" output="toHtml" template="page/html/series.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>

</layout>
```

Now that your block is defined for the header, you can now call it in your **templates/page/header.phtml** file.  You can output your block like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('serieMenu') ?>
```

Remember that modifiyng layout files will require you to flush your Magento caches, if you have cache management enabled.

Comment: Gets me a bit closer to understanding how it works, but doesn't solve the problem. The HTML is just totally at the bottom. My theme (modern) already had a page.xml so I edited it, but for testing I did as you suggested.

I made a local.xml containing the text you wrote up here.
I put the getChildHtml in my header.phtml
and wrote some code (but it could also contain echo "test"; in  page/html/series.phtml

Still it outputs in the footer. So I'm thinking I did something wrong with my block(Except for the things I described above I did nothing). output: http://magento.tijdelijkonline.nl/magento